# How to use SQLite from Services in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, service

It's sad how hard it is to find a simple line of code that does this "In my opinion".

Anyhow, the problem is I have a program with activities and services "I am new to services". 
 I can access my SQLite DataBase from activities using

TheDB class:

```
public TheDB(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
    this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

And then I can just call the methods, e.g.

myActivity class:

```
private TheDB db;
bla... bla... bla...
this.db = new TheDB(this);
db.insertSomething(id, name);
```

TheDB class (method called from myActivity):

```
public void insertSomething(String id, String name){
    db.execSQL("INSERT into " + farmsTable
+ " (id, name)"
+ " Values "
+ " (" + id + ", '" + name  + "')");
}
```

ALL I want to be able to do is call TheDB's methods from my service like I do from myActivity.

Do I make a new constructor? Do I change the way I instantiate it?

Comment: hi brotha, i did try that however it keeps saying "The method TheDB(Context) is undefined for the type myService" mY service code is: public class myService extends Service {

 public TheDB db;
 Context context;
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
     context = getApplicationContext();
     this.db = TheDB(context);
    }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do it in the same way you did it for your activity. The only thing that you need to instantiate `TheDB` is a context; `Activity` is a `Context` as well as `Service`.

Comment: hi brotha, i did try that however it keeps saying "The method TheDB(Context) is undefined for the type myService"

Comment: here's my code: public class myService extends Service {

 public TheDB db;
 Context context;
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
     context = getApplicationContext();
     this.db = TheDB(context);
    }

Comment: You are missing the `new` keyword.

Comment: looooooooooooooooooooool, thats the 2nd time I do it! you're a life saver mate thanks heaps!

Comment: @ZiGi u rock!  the key is context = getApplicationContext();  the rest is just boilerplate.

Comment: @ZiGi Why can I just access getApplicationContext() from the constructor ?