# IBM Worklight - Can SQLite be used to share data between Android service and Webview?

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I need to save an id through the Webview and then access it through my Android service.

I would like to know if I can use SQLite in my Webview (via cordova interface) and
also from my Android service, while accessing the same database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Cordova uses Web SQL for Storage: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html
2. There is, however, a Cordova plug-in to use SQLite: https://github.com/pgsqlite/PG-SQLitePlugin-Android

   To learn how to use Cordova plug-ins in Worklight, [see these IBM Worklight Getting Started  training modules](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova)
3. You should then be able to access the database from the Android service: [How to use SQLite from Services in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242165/how-to-use-sqlite-from-services-in-android)

I am guessing the Android service will run only when the app is not running? I don't know if there will be any conflicts if both run at the same time.

Comment: actually the service and the webview is running simultaneous, is there a better way to save this <key,value> in another container that can be accessed by both?(besides Sqlite :))

Comment: Okay. As said I am not sure there won't be any conflicts. Best is to try and see...