# Using an SQLite database from a service in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-service

I would like to find out if the following is possible. I want to have an activity and a service that both make changes to a database, will the service still be able to access and change the content of the database once the activity stops running?

I know that the service can run independent of the activity once it is closed, but just not sure if database access will still be able to continue?

Comment: There is no problem access db from services in Android..

Comment: You can always access your database from service also, there is no need of an application to run for that compulsory.

Comment: Did you [search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242165/how-to-use-sqlite-from-services-in-android)?

Comment: yes its possible. It require no UI. It will work in background

Comment: @FlamePrincessϡ yeah I did search, I think the bigger question here is being missed. Can the service continue to use the database even when the application has been closed and killed off?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can use sqlite database in your Service, even if application goes to background, or application is killed using swipe from Recent application list.

I created a very simple [demo](https://github.com/MysticMagic/ServiceAndSqlite).

Its just a database with an empty table. And I am getting whether table contains any record or not in Service at every 10 seconds. Its giving me toast message even if application is in background, or its killed.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MyDBHelper myDBHelper = new MyDBHelper(getApplicationContext());
            boolean isInfoAvailable = myDBHelper.isAnyInfoAvailable(getApplicationContext());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(isInfoAvailable), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 10 * 1000);
        }
    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 10 * 1000);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

All you would need to make sure is:

*Service should run in background.*

In your manifest file, use flag `android:stopWithTask="false"` for service.

```
<service
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:stopWithTask="false">
</service>
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Worked for me Thanks to awesome contribution.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible to have your service access the DB - try looking at [How to use SQLite from Services in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242165/how-to-use-sqlite-from-services-in-android)